# What is a Deductive Database?

Tags: database, prolog, datalog

I am reading some papers on databases and stumbled upon deductive databases. It seems that information on them is somewhat limited. The Wikipedia article states `A deductive database is a database system that can make deductions (i.e. conclude additional facts) based on rules and facts stored in the (deductive) database.`, but that is somewhat of a vague explanation. How are rules stored in databases? I read about Datalog as a query language for such databases, but I also read this article. [https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node11.html#:~:text=Prolog%20is%20an%20elegant%20language,a%20powerful%20subset%20of%20SQL](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ewarren/xsbbook/node11.html#:%7E:text=Prolog%20is%20an%20elegant%20language,a%20powerful%20subset%20of%20SQL). Now the question becomes how is a deductive database different from a system constructed by a regular SQL database and analyzed by an application written in a logical programming language such as Prolog. I apologize if my questions are plain stupid, but it's hard to grasp on their real intention. Are there any real uses nowadays for such databases? All the papers I read on them are from 1990 and there don't seem to be any new advancements.

Comment: _"There don't seem to be any new advancements"_. Not as much as one would like, indeed. "Deductive databases" would be incarnated in the form of "RDBMS" + "ad-hoc Java/C# engine on top", and one could think of a variation of Greenspun's Tenth Rule, maybe "Any sufficiently complicated program on top of an RDBMS contains an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of a deductive database system.". The problem may be that these systems are not taught to developers or engineers, and maybe that they do fit well what one would like them to do.

Comment: For example, the deductive database may need to gracefully handle contradictions and uncertain/nonmonotonic knowledge. Fragments of binary logic with negation-as-failure won't necessarily be sufficient. The language must also have rich modeling concept built-in (see [Flora-2](http://flora.sourceforge.net/)). As a recent development see [Knowledge Graphs](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2021/3/250711-knowledge-graphs/fulltext), and example of which is [GRAKN](https://grakn.ai/).